# How to display static table/grid in UWP without using itemsource?

Tags: xaml, listview, gridview, uwp, grid

For my project, I want to display a grid/table with 3 rows having 4 columns on each row in UWP applicatoin. All the columns will have a textbox control. I don't want to display any data on the grid rather I want to take the input from user. I've tried grid/gridview control. I'm not really sure how I can specify the xaml for displaying 3 rows and 4 columns with textbox control? Something like this picture.[image]

Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried Telerik controls - RadDataGridView?

Comment: No. I was trying to use basic UWP controls.

Comment: There is no GridView control in UWP to fulfill your requirements, you need to use third-party controls only

Comment: Did you mean this one ? 
https://www.telerik.com/universal-windows-platform-ui/grid

Comment: Exaclty, it is customizable to your need and also there is open source version available.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But is it possible to use the basic grid controls with border? Defining the 0th row as header with textblock and all other row as per my requirement?? May be having grids inside grids? What do you think about it?

Comment: You can obviously do that, but why would you do that if you are getting the product ready, Changes you will do will require more changes if needs extension and also will not be as good as library code

Comment: You're absolutely right. Thanks

Comment: @ipsit - Can you please help with any documentation or example link with telerik's raddatagrid to fulfill my requirement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**XAML**

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid x:Name="MyTableGrid" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Border Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Black">
            <TextBlock Text="Column 1" FontSize="25" TextAlignment="Center"/>
        </Border>
        <Border Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Black">
            <TextBlock Text="Column 2" FontSize="25" TextAlignment="Center"/>
        </Border>
        <Border Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Black">
            <TextBlock Text="Column 3" FontSize="25" TextAlignment="Center"/>
        </Border>
        <Border Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Black">
            <TextBlock Text="Column 4" FontSize="25" TextAlignment="Center"/>
        </Border>


        <Border Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Black">
            <TextBox BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="5" Height="65" Width="135"/>
        </Border>
        <Border Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"  BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Black">
            <TextBox BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="5" Height="65" Width="135"/>
        </Border>
        <Border Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Black">
            <TextBox BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="5" Height="65" Width="135"/>
        </Border>
        <Border Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Black">
            <TextBox BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="5" Height="65" Width="135"/>
        </Border>
        <Border Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Black">
            <TextBox BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="5" Height="65" Width="135"/>
        </Border>
        <Border Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Black">
            <TextBox BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="5" Height="65" Width="135"/>
        </Border>
        <Border Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Black">
            <TextBox BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="5" Height="65" Width="135"/>
        </Border>
        <Border Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="2" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Black">
            <TextBox BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="5" Height="65" Width="135"/>
        </Border>
        <Border Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Black">
            <TextBox BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="5" Height="65" Width="135"/>
        </Border>
        <Border Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Black">
            <TextBox BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="5" Height="65" Width="135"/>
        </Border>
        <Border Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="3" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Black">
            <TextBox BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="5" Height="65" Width="135"/>
        </Border>
        <Border Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="3" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Black">
            <TextBox BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="5" Height="65" Width="135"/>
        </Border>
    </Grid>        
</Grid>
```

**Output**

[image: Output]

I made rough sample of your screen shot you can edit height and width of row and column in row and column definition, currently i haven't set any height and width & it is for general idea so you need to customize it in your own way

**Suggestion**

add new user control page and and use it as table and then reference it in your main-page so whenever you want you want you can customize it separately and data binding and saving user input more clearly

Comment: Thanks :). Is it possible to iterate through the grid controls by row basis from code behind?

Comment: you can insert "Name" in grid and other element to intract with elements in code behind

Comment: @XavierXie-MSFT - Using telerik's data grid to solve this problem.

Comment: @user1814131 If you have resolved your issue, you could add a answer in this thread and mark it as [accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) to convenient people who visit this thread later.