# Table in UWP App

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have some UWP apps in Microsoft/Windows Store, and I want develop a new UWP app. It is a simple and static application, and I want to put a table (with always equal data - static), but I have already been searching and found nothing of how to make a table in a UWP app (XAML and C #).

Is it possible to create a table in a UWP app?

Comment: A table is a [grid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.grid) of cells.

Comment: Use a GridView :)

Comment: You could use a third party control like Telerik's controls for UWP - [Telerik Grid](https://www.telerik.com/universal-windows-platform-ui/grid)

Comment: You have two option first is use grid and borders https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47406382/how-to-display-static-table-grid-in-uwp-without-using-itemsource/47406726#47406726 or second use telerik grid

Answer (score 2):

As said in the comments, you can use [Telerik Grid](https://www.telerik.com/universal-windows-platform-ui/grid). However, if you want to build the table yourself the [Grid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Grid) control will suffice.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

The above will create a grid with 3 rows and 3 columns. If you want to autosize the columns:

```
<ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
<RowDefinition Width="Auto"/>
```

This will create, respectively, a column that sizes itself based on the amount of available space and a row that sizes itself to its content.

To make your grid look like a table (ie. borders between each cell), use the border control:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
        ...
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
        ...
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Border Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2">
        //Content here
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

You can place the Border control in each 'cell' by adjusting the Grid.Row and Grid.Column properties.

Answer (score 1):

The most recent version of Windows Community Toolkit features the DataGrid https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/datagrid. I haven't used it myself so I don't know how easy or hard data binding it is but it looks very capable.

Answer (score 0):

The Grid nad ListView are OK, but the DataGrid control will be the best choice.
Under the link you will find the MS documentation for it:
[Windows Community Toolkit DataGrid XAML control documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/datagrid)
     
It's best to use a native solution and not reinvent the wheel from scratch.

Example bellow:

```
<controls:DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid1" 
Height="600" Margin="12"
AutoGenerateColumns="False"
ItemsSource="{x:Bind MyViewModel.Customers}">
<controls:DataGrid.Columns>
    <!-- Name Column -->
    <controls:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Name">
        <controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    <TextBlock Padding="5,0,5,0"
                        Text="{x:Bind FirstName}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind LastName}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate> 
        <controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBox Text="{x:Bind FirstName}" BorderThickness="0"/>
                    <TextBox Text="{x:Bind LastName}" BorderThickness="0"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate> 
    </controls:DataGridTemplateColumn>              
    <!-- other columns below -->
</controls:DataGrid>
```